# Heroku migration to Cedar - "ERROR: No application configured, nothing to run"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration, puma, cedar

I am trying to migrate my old Heroku Ruby on Rails application from Bamboo to Cedar stack. I am using Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.11 and Postgres database.

I do everything as described on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration but by application start I get the message in heroku log:

```
"ERROR: No application configured, nothing to run"
```

My Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

config/puma.rb:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.8.7'
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.3'
gem 'rails', '2.3.11'
gem 'puma'
gem 'pg', '0.14.1'
gem 'rdoc'
```

Rakefile:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

Local bundle install works fine. I invoke command like this on the server:

```
$ heroku buildpack:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby#legacy-ruby-1.8.7
```

After pushing commit to Heroku and performing successful database migration I am still getting logs:

```
2015-03-11T19:09:53.619567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-03-11T19:09:53.614080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-03-11T19:09:57.902538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-03-11T19:10:00.320289+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Version 2.11.1 (ruby 1.8.7-p376), codename: Intrepid Squirrel
2015-03-11T19:10:00.320353+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2015-03-11T19:10:00.320162+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2015-03-11T19:10:00.320497+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Preloading application
2015-03-11T19:10:00.320396+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Environment: production
2015-03-11T19:10:00.320452+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Process workers: 2
2015-03-11T19:10:00.320593+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ERROR: No application configured, nothing to run
2015-03-11T19:10:01.138174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-03-11T19:10:01.145537+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

---

Edit 1:

Малъ, thank you for your answer. I performed all of the steps you recommend up to point 8. Then I pushed changes to Heroku. Logs are now like that:

```
2015-03-14T19:16:17.146877+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup -s puma -p ${PORT:-3000} -E ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
2015-03-14T19:16:18.986661+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.986682+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem.source_index called from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.987408+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.987505+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.987522+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:322.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.988403+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.989216+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.989842+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.988482+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.989863+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.987432+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! called from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:34.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.989238+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.990514+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.994219+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.994225+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.994227+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:16:18.994229+00:00 app[web.1]: ./config/environment.rb:43: warning: already initialized constant MONTHNAMES
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112792+00:00 app[web.1]: ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks': can't activate rack (~> 1.1.0), already activated rack-1.4.5. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (RuntimeError)
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112798+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:134:in `process'
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112808+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112806+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2:in `require'
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112802+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./config/environment.rb:9
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:0:in `new'
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112810+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:0
2015-03-14T19:16:19.112807+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2
2015-03-14T19:16:19.870706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-03-14T19:16:19.882290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Then I try to updating rack version in Gemfile to 1.1.0, invoked

```
$ bundle update rack
```

and uploaded sources once again. Logs:

```
2015-03-14T19:08:30.722782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-03-14T19:08:35.270101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup -s puma -p ${PORT:-3000} -E ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
2015-03-14T19:08:39.383233+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/handler.rb:21:in `get'
2015-03-14T19:08:39.383209+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/handler.rb:21:in `const_get': wrong constant name puma (NameError)
2015-03-14T19:08:39.383245+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rackup:23
2015-03-14T19:08:39.383236+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/server.rb:159:in `server'
2015-03-14T19:08:39.383239+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/server.rb:83:in `start'
2015-03-14T19:08:39.383242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/bin/rackup:4
2015-03-14T19:08:39.383238+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/server.rb:155:in `start'
2015-03-14T19:08:39.383243+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2015-03-14T19:08:40.314387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-03-14T19:08:40.299712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Now I don't know completely how I could deal with that.

---

Edit 2:

I noticed that the sed command failed and didn't changed vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller.rb so I've added lacking line to it:

```
gem 'rack', '~> 1.4.0'
```

Current logs:

```
2015-03-14T19:53:59.803670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-03-14T19:54:03.524424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup -s puma -p ${PORT:-3000} -E ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
2015-03-14T19:54:05.617313+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem.source_index called from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.618457+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.621176+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.617253+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.623472+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.618569+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.620427+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.620459+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.622667+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.618490+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! called from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:34.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.621896+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.624954+00:00 app[web.1]: ./config/environment.rb:43: warning: already initialized constant MONTHNAMES
2015-03-14T19:54:05.618605+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:322.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751623+00:00 app[web.1]: ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks': can't activate rack (~> 1.1.0), already activated rack-1.4.5. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (RuntimeError)
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751649+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:134:in `process'
2015-03-14T19:54:05.621928+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.622636+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./config/environment.rb:9
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751802+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751707+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751687+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751841+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:0:in `new'
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751765+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751746+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2:in `require'
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751822+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2015-03-14T19:54:05.751859+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:0
2015-03-14T19:54:05.621284+00:00 app[web.1]: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
2015-03-14T19:54:05.623441+00:00 app[web.1]: NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
2015-03-14T19:54:06.627025+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-03-14T19:54:06.613881+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

---

Edit 3:

I forgot to delete the line with rack 1.1.0 version in vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller.rb. Now application is up and works like a charm. Малъ, you are my salvator! Big thanks.

Comment: I have Rails 2.3.11 as I wrote.

Comment: Just change the line manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some steps to run my `Rails 2.3` app on heroku `cedar-10` stack. Unfortunately it will be also removed soon, in such way the heroku support answered. So:

1. Upgrade or downgrade `rubygems` to `1.4.2`, it is required to run `rake` freeze:

   ```
   $ gem update --system 1.4.2
   ```
2. Add `rake` into **Gemfile**. and bundle setup.
3. According the [manual](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/12), you have to at first freeze `Rails` gems into **/vendor** folder:

   ```
   $ rake rails:freeze:gems
   ```
4. Modify file: **vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller.rb** to support `rack 1.4.0` version:

   ```
   $ sed "s/gem 'rack', '~> 1.1.0'/gem 'rack', '~> 1.4.0'/" -i vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller.rb
   ```
5. Add `rack 1.4.0`, and `puma 2.3.2` gems to **Gemfile**, and *remove* `rails` gem from it, then bundle setup again:

   ```
   gem 'rack', '~> 1.4.0'
   gem 'puma', '~> 2.3.2'
   ```

   **NOTE:** the **config/puma.rb** is also not needed anymore.
6. Change **Procfile** to run `puma` via `rackup`:

   ```
   $ cat Procfile
   web: bundle exec rackup -s puma -p ${PORT:-3000} -E ${RACK_ENV:-development}
   ```
7. Add **config.ru** to run `Rails` app from `rackup`:

   ```
   $ cat config.ru
   # RAILS_ROOT/config.ru
   require "config/environment"

   use Rails::Rack::LogTailer
   use Rails::Rack::Static
   run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
   ```
8. Add the changed and newly added files into git, and push changes to heroku.
9. Since the heroku uses `PostgreSQL` in production by default, create `MySQL` db instance, of course if you plan to use it, accoriding the [manual](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb):

   ```
   $ heroku addons:add cleardb:ignite
   -----> Adding cleardb to sharp-mountain-4005... done, v18 (free)

   $ heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
   CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL => mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true

   $ heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'
   ```

Comment: @Kaktusiarz so what have you got?

Comment: Next steps described.

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly I had to remove server variable

```
STACK:                      bamboo-ree-1.8.7
```

and add

```
RAILS_ENV:                  production
```

Now, the original application (not a test copy of it) works.

Regards,

Michał

Answer (score 0):

Anyway first try to add config.ru at end of line (Rails 3.X.X)

My Procfile

```
web:  bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb config.ru
```